# Haskell: Combining Maybe and Either types to a single type

Tags: haskell, types

I have to combined `Maybe` and `Either` into `MayEither`, with three constructors for `Left`, `Right` and `Nothing` called `MyLeft`, `MyRight` and `MyNothing`.

This is what I did:

```
data MayEither = Maybe  { myNothing :: Nothing }
               | Either { myLeft :: Left }
               | Either { myRight :: Right } deriving Show
```

But this gives me a `Multiple declarations of ‘Either’` error.
How can I properly combine the types?

Comment: What is wrong with `MayEither l r = Maybe (Either l r)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things need to happen:

1. You need to give distinct names for each of your data constructors.
2. You need to give the types of the fields in your records.

Note that `Nothing`, `Left`, and `Right` are *data constructors* for the `Maybe` and `Either` types -- they are not themselves types! So claiming that a field has type `Nothing` isn't quite right. Similarly, `Maybe` and `Either` are type constructors, so naming your data constructors after them is at best misleading, and in this case almost certainly simply wrong.

So let's try again. First we'll pick new data constructor names.

```
data MayEither = MyNothing { myNothing :: <TODO> }
               | MyLeft { myLeft :: <TODO> }
               | MyRight { myRight :: <TODO> }
```

Now, what type should `myNothing` have? Well, the whole point of `Nothing`/`MyNothing` is that there's, well, nothing there. So we shouldn't have that field at all!

```
data MayEither = MyNothing
               | MyLeft { myLeft :: <TODO> }
               | MyRight { myRight :: <TODO> }
```

What type should the `myLeft` field have? Well, presumably we'd like to be able to have anything in there. The way to allow that is to parameterize our type -- just like `Maybe` takes one type-level argument and `Either` takes two type-level arguments. We'll do what `Either` does, and take two arguments, so that our `myLeft` and `myRight` fields can be arbitrary and need not match.

```
data MayEither a b = MyNothing
                   | MyLeft { myLeft :: a }
                   | MyRight { myRight :: b }
```

This is now valid Haskell. BUT combining record syntax and sum types is almost always a bad idea. I think I would drop the field names entirely, if I were doing this myself.

```
data MayEither a b = MyNothing
                   | MyLeft a
                   | MyRight b
-- OR
data MayEither a b = MyNothing | MyLeft a | MyRight b
```

Comment: “Combining record syntax and sum types is almost always a bad idea” historically because field selector functions such as `myLeft :: MayEither a b -> a` raise an error if the field isn’t present in all constructors. However, you can now use the [`NoFieldSelectors`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/field_selectors.html) language option to disable these functions, and still benefit from giving descriptive names to your datatype fields.

Comment: @JonPurdy I guess I'm also a bit queasy about record update, which still seems to be available with that extension. Should I feel differently?

Comment: Good point, I use [`-Wincomplete-record-updates`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-record-updates) but I’d forgotten that it isn’t on by default. The docs say “it can be very noisy” but I haven’t actually had an issue with that. If I’m doing a lot of record updates, I’ve almost always defined a separate record type anyway, referencing it from the sum type.

Comment: @JonPurdy Yeah, having a separate record and referencing it in my sum is my preferred solution as well.